# sorting into uneven bins with some patterns

Tags: matlab

I hope to bin the following data, `x1 = [1 2 5 200 201]` into 5 bins.

Hence for

```
x1(1) = 1st bin
x1(2) = 2nd bin
and ... 
x1(5) = 5th bin.
```

if `x2` has 6 values, put `x2 = [1 2 5 70 200 201]` into 5 bins.

Hence

```
x2(1) = 1st bin
x2(2) = 2nd bin
x2(3) = 3rd bin
x2(4) = 3rd bin
x2(5) = 4th bin
x2(6) = 5th bin
```

if `x3` has 7 values, put `x3 = [1 2 5 10 70 200 201]` into 5 bins.

Hence

```
x2(1) = 1st bin
x2(2) = 1st bin
x2(3) = 2nd bin
x2(4) = 3rd bin
x2(5) = 4th bin
x2(6) = 5th bin
x2(7) = 5th bin
```

In real dataset, I have more observations but it will be sorted into 5 bins.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the question is. Do you want to create a histogram?

Comment: Explain the logic behind how you are assigning the bins. Are the bin edges predetermined or calculated somehow?

Comment: I would like to sort the data into bins. Here I have 5 bins. I have sort the data ascending. If I have 5 samples, I would put the first sample into bin 1, the next sample in bin 2, the next sample in bin 3, the following next sample into bin 4 and the last sample into the last bin (bin 5).

Comment: The problem comes when the samples are uneven. Example, if there are 6 samples, I will put the 3rd and 4th samples into bin 3. The rest remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand how you wish to group the data into what bin. I would suggest having a look at either

```
Y=discretize(x1,edges);
```

or

```
[N, edges, bin]=histcounts(x1,5);
```

#### UPDATE

If you are trying to bin the data evenly you could always do:

```
X = 1:6; % Example data
Nbins=5; % number of bins
i=linspace(1,Nbins,length(X)); % distribute X evenly onto bin-space

[~,~,bin]=histcounts(round(i)); % bin evenly distributed data.

for j=1:Nbins
    binnedData{j}=X(bin==j);
end
celldisp(binnedData)
```

which will output an evenly distributed binning of your data.

Comment: I think I cant use it. Histcounts will always bin the leftover observations from left to right.

Comment: X = [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29];
[N,edges] = histcounts(X,6)




N =

     2     2     2     2     1     1


edges =

         0    4.9000    9.8000   14.7000   19.6000   24.5000   29.4000

Comment: For this example, I need N = 2 2 1 1 2 2

Comment: I think you still need to clarify the logic behind your bin distribution better. Three examples are not enough to go on, especially if you don't describe why the data is supposed to be binned that way. Is it the even-ness you are looking for?